# Делаю пост запрос, устанавливаю куки сайта, все равно не пропускает

Tags: c#, httpclient

Пытаюсь осуществить вход в инстаграм, устанавливаю куки, которые дает сайт, отправляю пост запрос, но все равно не пропускает. Пробовал через postman, его тоже не пропускает.

```
            string data;
            var baseAddress = new Uri("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher");
            var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer };
                var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = baseAddress };
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "*/*");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AcmeInc/1.0)");

            var result = await client.GetAsync(baseAddress);
                data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Uri url = new Uri("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/");
            IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = cookieContainer.GetCookies(url).Cast<Cookie>();

            var uidCookie = responseCookies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "csrftoken");
            var uidCookie1 = responseCookies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "ig_did");
            var uidCookie2 = responseCookies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "rur");
            var uidCookie3 = responseCookies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "mid");

            Console.WriteLine(uidCookie);

            cookieContainer.Add(uidCookie);
            cookieContainer.Add(uidCookie1);
            cookieContainer.Add(uidCookie2);
            cookieContainer.Add(uidCookie3);

            HttpContent content = new StringContent("username=89895354251&enc_password=%23PWD_INSTAGRAM_BROWSER%3A6%3A1585846985%3AAZpQALTouH3pUzEA1rHsgDTDt7aVXCH6AjnQH0NpFKkX0PQbzgNStO1H1ZmaZS6EmrX48aiqThdidj4hZyim7EdyV0SAFtkJSGgw%2ByNPhDYHNYf8j2tW6KuI91aITqZlC%2B5clPKBDg9O16mA&password=mockva56&queryParams=%7B%7D&optIntoOneTap=false",
                                    Encoding.UTF8,
                                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var result2 = await client.PostAsync("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/ajax/", content);
            var data2 = await result2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(data2+"   |||    "+ result2.StatusCode);
```

Пробовал baseadress устанавливать для получения куки, вместо пост адреса, все равно так же

Comment: там кроме кук браузер много всякого ещё отправляет. Например, те же заголовки. И это, разве у инсты нет своего API?

Comment: Я пытаюсь без API сделать. А разве заголовки он автоматически не устанавливает, которые браузер дает

Comment: кто он? Никто тут ничего автоматически не устанавливает. Вот браузер себе на уме, а когда вы руками запросы посылаете - тут самим все придется сделать.